# 'String index out of range' error and I don't understand why

Tags: python, cs50, indexoutofrangeexception

I'm trying to take an input, drop the vowels, and print the new phrase.

#### Code

Here's the code I'm using.

```
phrase = input("Input: ")
for i in range(len(phrase)):
    if str(phrase[i]) in ["a", "A", "e", "E", "i", "I", "O", "o", "u", "U"]:  # error at this line
        phrase = str(phrase[i]).replace(phrase[i], "")
print(phrase)
```

#### Issue

On line 3, I am getting the error:

> string index out of range

I don't understand how, since I thought I limited the index to the length of the phrase.

Even if there are better ways to create this script (and I would love any suggestions), I would also really love to know where what I'm doing is going wrong and how to fix it!

Comment: Your loop is going to run from 0 through the ORIGINAL length of `phrase`.  After you remove vowels, `phrase` is not going to be that length any more.  You should never modify a list or string as you are iterating over it.  A better plan is to create a new string only keeping the characters you want.

Comment: Consider using https://cs50.stackexchange.com if related to the CS50 course.

Comment: @TimRoberts Your comment is explaining the issue and a good advice which could be beneficially moved to your answer 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't need `i` as index or `range(len(phrase))` to replace a character or to drop certain character in `phrase` string, If you're intend to take an input, drop the vowels, and print the new phrase.

```
phrase = input("Input: ")
for i in phrase:
    if i in ["a", "A", "e", "E", "i", "I", "O", "o", "u", "U"]:
        phrase = phrase.replace(i, "")
print(phrase)
```

Comment: Wow, naturally appealing solution to __replace exiting vowels__ with empty-string (equivalent to _remove_ or _drop_ them).

Comment: Maybe appealing, but imperfect and wasteful.  It's STILL a dangerous practice to modify a sequence while you are iterating through it.  Do `print(i)` in this loop, and you'll see that it iterates over every letter in the ORIGINAL string, even though we have modified it.  Also, remember that `phrase.replace('a','')` replaces EVERY occurrence of `'a'`, even though we will be iterating over them later.

Answer (score 3):

Don't modify the string while you iterate over it.  Just keep the letters you want:

```
phrase = input("Input: ")
new = []
for c in phrase:
    if c not in "aeiouAEIOU":
        new.append(c)
phrase = ''.join(new)
print(phrase)
```

Or:

```
phrase = ''.join([c for c in phrase if c not in "aeiuoAEIUO"])
```

Comment: Micro-optimization.  Appending to a string requires creating a NEW string object and destroying the old one.  `list.append` modifies the list in place.  Years ago, string operations were much less efficient than list operations.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the reason to use this list, because when reading with a simple mind (like a newbie) it appears un-natural and the later join seems an additional statement to stumble upon. In production-code I would definitely add a comment to rectify this implementation choice.

Answer (score 2):

#### Spotted Issues

3 issues and 1 improvement:

1. `for i in range(len(phrase)):`: (a) `len` of string is a snapshot which will does not fit anymore as soon as the first vowel was removed. (b) indexed for-i loop can be replaced by a for-each loop `for c in phrase` which loops through each character of a string
2. `if str(phrase[I]) in ["a", "A", "e", "E", "i", "I", "O", "o", "u", "U"]`: (a) string-conversion is not needed, `phrase[i]` or `c` can be compared to string element already. (b) can directly compare if character is in a string of vowels: `if c in "aAeEiIoOuU"`
3. `phrase = str(phrase[i]).replace(phrase[i], "")`: replace parts inside a whole, like a character inside a string using `phrase = phrase.replace("a", "")` - don't replace the single character at a position.
4. `phrase = input("Input: ")`: **to improve** towards a reproducible example, provide the input as fixed given example: `phrase = "Hello World with many Vowels"` instead depending on interactive user-input.

#### Solution

I would suggest a combination of the good answers here:

1. loop for each character in string like suggested by Tim
2. add to a `new_phrase` like suggested by LLSv2.0
3. drop by replace with empty-string like tried by you and suggested by ANC
4. compare agains given vowels from a string like `"aAeEiIoOuU"` like Tim did

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're updating `phrase` while iterating through from 0 to the *original* length of `phrase`. The second you drop a character in phrase, the max valid subscript decreases while `i` will still reach the original phrase length.

You could do this better with `filter`.

```py
phrase = input("Input: ")
new_phrase = "".join(filter(lambda c: c not in "aAeEiIoOuU", phrase))
print(new_phrase)
```

Comment: Might be a correct solution, but introducing _lambda_ functions and even equivalent _list-comprehension_ like in Tim's answer might overwhelm a newbie practicing with a CS50 course. These are  advanced concepts that need explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the issue is that you are re-writing the entire `phrase` variable with a singular character and then you are trying to loop over it again.

In the 4th line, you set `phrase` equal to a single character, and then you try to loop over it again but then you have `phrase[i]`, but `phrase` itself now is just length of 1. So if `i` is greater than 1 (it probably is) it can't do that.

Also, you can loop directly over a string and it will return each character of the string directly.

Try building a new string in line 4 instead, something like

```py
phrase = input("Input: ")
new_string = ''
for i in phrase:
    if i not in ["a", "A", "e", "E", "i", "I", "O", "o", "u", "U"]:
        new_string += i
print(new_string)
```

edit: update code based off of comments

Answer (score -3):

If I am not wrong, it returns "IndexError: string index out of range", since you can only access one position of the string. By entering a single character or number it works perfectly.

Comment: _"If I am not wrong"_: You are. The error occurs when you try to access an index of the string that does not exist. What do you mean by "you can only access one position of the string"?